# Apache .htaccess mod_rewrite not working to create "Pretty URLs"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

## I am trying to make URLs seen by users look "pretty."

(E.G), make URL:

http://localhost.com/search/?query=multiple+words+seperated+by+pluses

Look like:

http://localhost.com/search/multiple+words+seperated+by+pluses

### The part of my `.htaccess` file that deals with rewrites looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /search/?query=$1
</IfModule>
```

### To find out what is wrong, I tested a few things:

1. I went over to a [Rewrite Rule Tester](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) to see if my rule worked for the desired income.  The resulting URL was as expected, so I concluded that the problem was caused by the server.
2. Next, I replaced the first part of my `RewriteRule, "^search/(.*)$"` with `"^.*$"` to select all URLs, and replaced the second part of the `RewriteRule, "^search/(.*)$"` to `/index.php` to `Rewrite` them to the home page in order to test if the `RewriteRule` was working.  It worked, leaving me even more confused.

   - RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php

**Any** suggestions will be very appreciated.

> NOTE: I know that some servers require adding the option `FollowSymLinks` to the `.htaccess` file, but when I tried to see if this was the case with my server, my error log reported:
>
> `[Sun Dec 20 03:43:53 2015] [warn] [client Option FollowSymLinks not allowed in line __ of /home/sites/localhost.com/.htaccess.`
>
> NOTE: Right now, http://localhost.com/search/multiple+words+seperated+by+pluses is returning a 404 (Page Not Found) error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this rule inside **`/search/.htaccess`**:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /search/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ?query=$1 [L,QSA]
```